# apollo-server Error: CountryCode.name was defined in resolvers, but not present within CountryCode

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I recently upgraded my nodejs/express/graphQL project dependencies as follows:

- express: from 4.17.1 to 4.17.3
- apollo-server-express: from 2.22.2 to 3.6.7
- graphql: from 15.5.0 to 16.3.0

I did not change anything in my typedefs/resolvers which worked fine before the update, but now I'm getting the following error upon instantiating the ApolloServer class from "apollo-server-express":

```
Error: CountryCode.name was defined in resolvers, but not present within CountryCode
at addResolversToSchema (/server/api/node_modules/@graphql-tools/schema/index.js:155:27)
at makeExecutableSchema (/server/api/node_modules/@graphql-tools/schema/index.js:501:14)
at ApolloServer.constructSchema (/server/api/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts:643:32)
at null.ApolloServerBase (/server/api/node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/ApolloServer.ts:283:18)
at null.ApolloServer (/server/api/node_modules/apollo-server-express/src/ApolloServer.ts:55:1)
at null.main (/server/api/builds/dev/api-server.js:191:22)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

**Note the error message: this is not the usual "xyz defined in resolvers but not in typedefs" kind of error, which happens all the time when working with graphQL and I know how to fix.**
What's funny is that CountryCode is an enum, and therefore has no field named "name", as the error message suggests. Here is the typedef for the CountryCode enum:

```
const countryCodeTypedef = gql`
  enum CountryCode { af ax al <other-country-codes> }
`
```

where `<all-other-country-codes>` is a placeholder for all remaining country codes. Yes, I use lower-case enum values although it is not best practice, but the project started out this way and I can't change it now. It worked fine before the update however.

I looked it up and there is no trace of a .name field in my resolvers, nor in my whole code-base!

If I exclude the CountryCode enum, the server starts fine, but then my project doesn't work as expected.

Did something change in the way typedefs/resolvers are defined in apollo-server between v2 and v3?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Under the shower this morning, I suddenly realized what the root cause of the error was!

As part of the upgrade process, I also upgraded the "graphql-scalars" package from 1.9.0 to 1.17.0 and it turned out that a CountryCode" scalar was added there, and it conflicted with my own Enum definition.

All I had to do was to explicitly import only the graphQL scalars I need (before I was including them all), and leave the conflicting CountryCode scalar out.

A more specific error message from apollo-server like 'duplicate definition for type "CountryCode"' would have helped me to spot the error faster, but that's how things are: apollo-server and graphql are just great tools!